# How to debug a @Scheduled spring boot method or a service method?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, debugging

I've an existing spring boot application and now I need to debug some methods. Therefore these methods are `@Scheduled` or in service classes they are invoked automatically by the app.

Is there any option to invoke these methods via debugging? Or are there any other ways to do that without changing the source code? I could add an ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner but then I need to change the App sources.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't/don't want to change the source code, you can just check which services are using the methods you need to test/debug, and call the services using POSTMAN.

Answer (score 3):

You can externalize the value for the `@Scheduled` annotation using SpEL. You still need to change the code but afterwards it's configurable and you can change the cron without changing the code. That way you can start it with a different cron for debugging too.

An alternative if you aren't able to change the code is to use remote debugging but you would need to restart the app for that and add the arguments mentioned in this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-running-as-a-packaged-application).

But that way it may take a lot of time for scheduled methods to get invoked depending on the cron or interval.

Comment: Okay, so it is not possible to invoke the method via remote debugging?

Comment: Not as far as I know but you can expose methods via jmx and invoke them that way but that requires code changes as well. See here for reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jmx.html

Comment: will this allow us to change the scheduling time without restarting the app?

Comment: @Fakipo not out of the box as far as I know, but SpEL can be extended to enable such functionality with custom methods. You could i.e. write a function that checks a file for updates and provides the values.